# Set attributes of libraries

Tags: android, apache, https, android-manifest, libraries

I am developing an app in which I need to retrieve data from an online database and I am importing HttpClient, HttpEntity, HttpPost etc.

Now, the issue I have is the following message "no main manifest attribute, in C:\Users(......)"

hence I opened the manifest.mf of these libraries, but I can't find any error nor "attribute" field.

Example of HttpClient

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: HttpComponents Apache HttpClient Cache
Implementation-Version: 4.5.1
Built-By: oleg
Specification-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.5
url: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client
X-Compile-Source-JDK: 1.6
Implementation-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_75
Specification-Title: HttpComponents Apache HttpClient Cache
Specification-Version: 4.5.1
Implementation-Build: tags/4.5.1-RC1/httpclient-cache@r1702448; 2015-0
 9-11 14:53:18+0200
X-Compile-Target-JDK: 1.6
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

I could not find any help on StackOverfFlow nor elsewhere on the internet: how can I set the attribute? Should I work also on the gradle file? Moreover, do I have to implement the manifests of ALL the libraries and in the SAME way?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I just replaced with HttpURLConnection but I am having issues, do you happen to know why?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView resultView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults(); //STRICT MODE ENABLED
    resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    String line=null;
    String [] stream_name;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    String value;
    getData();
}

public void getData(){
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL ("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        isr = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        resultView.setText("Couldn't connect to database");
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try {
        String s = "";
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s +
                    "Price : "+json.getString("Price")+"\n"+
                    "Weight : "+json.getInt("Weight")+"\n"+
                    "Price/Weight : "+json.getString("P/W")+"\n\n";
        }

        resultView.setText(s);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

My Php file is

```
<?php

  // PHP variable to store the host address
 $db_host  = "xxxxx";
 // PHP variable to store the username
 $db_uid  = "xxxxxx";
 // PHP variable to store the password
 $db_pass = "xxxxxxxx";
 // PHP variable to store the Database name  
 $db_name  = "xxxxxxx"; 
        // PHP variable to store the result of 

the PHP function 'mysql_connect()' which 

establishes the PHP & MySQL connection  
 $db_con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uid,

$db_pass) or die('could not connect');
 mysql_select_db($db_name);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE 1 WHERE ID = 'Bread AH'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  $output[]=$row;
 print(json_encode($output));
 mysql_close();   
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpClient is deprecated and was [completely removed in the latest release of Android 6.0](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client). You should be using [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to make network calls instead. If you actually need to use `HttpClient` for whatever reason, you would have to include this line in the `android` block of your manifest to make it work:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

---

**EDIT: In response to comments below...**

Here is some code I wrote to access an online DB via a web service. It makes a POST request to my server sending in some JSON data, and receives JSON in response, which I parse later in the code.

```
//The JSON we will get back as a response from the server
    JSONArray jsonResponse = null;

    //Http connections and data streams
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = null;

    try {

        //open connection to the server
            url = new URL("your_url_to_web_service");
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //set request properties
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true); //defaults request method to POST
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);  //allow input to this HttpURLConnection
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); //header params
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); //header params
            httpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(jsonToSend.toString().getBytes().length); //header param "content-length"

            //open output stream and POST our JSON data to server
            outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            outputStreamWriter.write(jsonToSend.toString());
            outputStreamWriter.flush(); //flush the stream when we're finished writing to make sure all bytes get to their destination

            //prepare input buffer and get the http response from server
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            //Check to make sure we got a valid status response from the server,
            //then get the server JSON response if we did.
            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                //read in each line of the response to the input buffer
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }

                bufferedReader.close(); //close out the input stream

            try {
                //Copy the JSON response to a local JSONArray
                jsonResponse = new JSONArray(stringBuilder.toString());
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                je.printStackTrace();
            }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(httpURLConnection != null) {
            httpURLConnection.disconnect(); //close out our http connection
        }

        if(outputStreamWriter != null) {
            try {
                outputStreamWriter.close(); //close our output stream
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //Return the JSON response from the server.
    return jsonResponse;
```

Comment: Hi @drschultz, thanks for your feedback. My purpose is to fetch data from an online MySQl and show it in an activity. Would HttpURLConnection fit it?

Comment: Yes! `HttpURLConnection` is great for getting data from an online database, and is the recommended method suggested by Google in the official docs. I'll add some sample code above of one of my methods that queries a web service to get data from an online DB using `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Hi DrSchultz, I can't find it in Android Studio. How do I manage to get it?

Comment: @MarcoDeRoni Find what? HttpURLConnection? To use the class you must import it. You must add this line to the top of your file: `import java.net.HttpURLConnection;`

Comment: could you check if the way I used HttpURLConnection is proper, please?